# How can I finish the current activity when performing a search in Android?

Tags: android, search, android-activity, android-searchmanager

I have search functionality in my app. When the search bar is invoked from a "show activity" and the user performs a search, I want to finish the show activity and take the user to the search activity. Is there a way to know if SearchManager.onDismissListener is invoked because of a search being performed?

What I want to avoid is to have several screens of search results > show > search results > show etc, and rather "go back" to search results whenever a search is performed, and thus only have one search activity and one show activity in the stack at any one time.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to prevent the search activity from being created multiple times.

[The impact of the search dialog on your activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#LifeCycle) in the Android docs has the explanation for what you want.

Essentially, you want to set `android:launchMode` to `"singleTop"` when defining your searchable activity in the manifest.  From the example at the link, you would then have something like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

But be careful to follow their advice for handling intents with `onCreate` and `onNewIntent`, which rather than duplicate here I'll just refer you to that link.

You can do the same for what your show activity as well with the `android:launchMode="singleTop"`